# Windows form application as outlook plugin installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, native

I have build C# windows form application using visual studio witch is simple outlook plugin installer. 
It does these steps:

1. generates GUID and stores it to windows registry (for logging purpose later in outlook plugin)
2. Downloads actual outluck install files
3. Launches outlook plugin installation

The problem is that I can run this setup if .net framework is not installed. Is there a way of checking is framework installed? Or maybe there is a way to convert this app to native windows application (without .net dependencies). Or maybe it is possible to include needed dll's only?

I have tried using mono mkbundle, but I am getting strange errors in windows like `Program too big to fit into memory` or something with wrong application architecture (x64 X86).

I have also found some commercial tools for that like .net fuze. So maybe there is free alternatives witch does something similar?

Or maybe this single file installer idea is wrong? Maybe I should use something different?

Comment: You can write a C++ application that does that for you and if framework installed - fire your plugin installer. But why complicate? Why not to use http://wixtoolset.org/? That will save you all that trouble.

Comment: @eddyuk thank you for suggestion. I have started reading documentation, but then I decited to use install shield solution with custom actions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx

Comment: Using installers projects for type of work you trying to achieve is a good idea.